# Can't find the Extention Manager in Joomla 2.5 after upgrading from 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I upgraded my site form joomla 1.5.26 to joomla 2.5.

After that i can't find the extension manager in administrator.

But there is no problem found during the upgrade.

Please give me an advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to

`/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer`

Than go to Database and click "Fix".

If you cannot access the link above go to:

```
/administrator/components/com_installer/installer.php
```

and TEMPORARY comment the if around the Access check.

Fix your database and remove the comment.

Comment: hi,i enterd this url, i got a message that "You are not authorised to view this resource.".But i logined as admin

Comment: /administrator/components/com_installer/installer.php  this page shows nothing.I can find only a blank page

Comment: try turning error logging on. you must see an error message somewhere